# can't read all the abstract Text from a pubmed xml file

Tags: python, xml, element, pubmed

I download a PubMed XML file and I want to print out all the article in this file here is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for abs_1 in root.findall("PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract"):
    abs_2 = abs_1.find('AbstractText').text
    print(abs_2)
```

however, I only get the objective part of the abstract. which is mark as `<AbstractText Label="AIM" NlmCategory="OBJECTIVE">` , I don't get the other two part which is also inside `<Abstract>`.

forxample the XML got something like this

```
<Abstract>
<AbstractText Label="AIM" NlmCategory="OBJECTIVE">The level of preparedness of the healthcare system plays an important role in management of coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19). This study attempted to devise a comprehensive protocol regarding dental care during the COVID-19 outbreak.</AbstractText>
<AbstractText Label="METHODS AND RESULT" NlmCategory="RESULTS">Embase, PubMed, and Google Scholar were searched until March 2020 for relevant papers. Sixteen English papers were enrolled to answer questions about procedures that are allowed to perform during the COVID-19 outbreak, patients who are in priority to receive dental care services, the conditions and necessities for patient admission, waiting room and operatory room, and personal protective equipment (PPE) that is necessary for dental clinicians and the office staff.</AbstractText>
<AbstractText Label="CONCLUSION" NlmCategory="CONCLUSIONS">Dental treatment should be limited to patients with urgent or emergency situation. By screening questionnaires for COVID-19, patients are divided into three groups of (a) apparently healthy, (b) suspected for COVID-19, and (c) confirmed for COVID-19. Separate waiting and operating rooms should be assigned to each group of patients to minimize the risk of disease transmission. All groups should be treated with the same protective measures with regard to PPE for the dental clinicians and staff.</AbstractText>
<CopyrightInformation>© 2020 Special Care Dentistry Association and Wiley Periodicals, Inc.</CopyrightInformation>
</Abstract>
```

Using my code I only get

```
The level of preparedness of the healthcare system plays an important role in management of coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19). This study attempted to devise a comprehensive protocol regarding dental care during the COVID-19 outbreak.
```

really need some help on how to print out all abstracttext inside abstract

Answer (score 0):

When you can `.findall()` `<Abstract>` elements, would it not be logical that you can `.findall()` `<AbstractText>` elements in the same way?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for AbstractText in root.findall("PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText"):
    print(AbstractText.text)
```